# Remove right border of facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, border, facet

I found posts about removing the right border of a single plot, but could not find posts about removing the right border of facets. 
Considering the facets produced by the following codes for example, is it possible to remove the right border of each facet?

```
    library(reshape2)
    library(ggplot2)
    sp <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + geom_point(shape=1)
    sp + facet_wrap( ~ day, ncol=2) + theme_bw() +
    theme(strip.text = element_text(size=12,colour="black"),
    strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, this is prbly the best you're going to be able to do:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

sp <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) 
sp <- sp + geom_point(shape=1)
sp <- sp + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
sp <- sp + geom_vline(xintercept=0)
sp <- sp + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
sp <- sp + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
sp <- sp + facet_wrap(~day, ncol=2)
sp <- sp + theme_bw()
sp <- sp + theme(panel.border=element_blank(),
                 strip.text=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
                 strip.background=element_rect(colour="white", 
                                               fill="white"))
sp
```

[image]

I'd prbly try to tweak the tick size to ensure they match the faux axes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @hrbrmstr!
But I still have one more question.
Is it possible to keep the tick marks on the facets axis?
Except for the “Sun” facet, the others all have tick marks missing on some axis.
The “Fri” facet has no tick marks on the x-axis, the “Thur” facet doesn’t have them on the y-axis and the “Sat” facet has no tick marks on any of its axis.
I was wondering if its possible to keep the tick marks on these facets axis.